# TextView and ImageView not changing on click

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an activity with three fragments placed in a ViewPager. On the first two fragments I have a list that drops down, kind of like an animated ExpandableListView but it is a simple RelativeLayout containing a TextView and ImageView, when pressed slides down a LinearLayout containing some elements. On clicking the RelativeLayout the followig actions are taken:

1. change the background color of the clicked RelativeLayout (works every time for every layout in every fragment)
2. change the color of the text in TextView (works every time for the first element I'll explain below)
3. animate the image, an arrow to change color and rotate (also works but for the first element)

**The problem is as follows:**
the first fragment contains only one list (a RelativeLayout that shows or hides a LinearLayout) and it works fine the background, text color and image change and the image rotates and the Linearlayout slides up and down correspondingly. The second fragment contains 4 such groupings (RelativeLayout controlling  LinearLayout) and on the first time this fragment is shown only the first grouping seems to work. The other three change background and slide the Linearlayout but as far as i can tell it keeps the same color and the same image (there are two colors a white and an orange that change and since the background changes from orange to white i assume the text stays white instead of changing to orange, same goes for the image).
**The punchline:**
when I leave it for a few seconds and click it again it works fine, everything changes accordingly, and if i for instance flip to the third fragment and back to the second it works. On the other hand if I start the app, got to the second fragment, back to the first, and to the second again it doesn't work.
I don't know if this has something to do with the GC and recycling views or something else.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nutritionList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboutWetFood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/wetSub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/wetLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@color/my_yellow"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="openNutrition"
                android:tag="wet" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wetTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/wet_food"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/wetArrow"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboutDryFood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/drySub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dryLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@color/my_yellow"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="openNutrition"
                android:tag="dry" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dryTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/dry_food"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dryArrow"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/whyMixedFeeding"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mixedSub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView08"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mixedLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@color/my_yellow"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="openNutrition"
                android:tag="mixed" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mixedTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/mixed_feeding"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mixedArrow"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/nutritionOralCare"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/oralSub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView09"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#EDEDED" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:text="SUB MENU 1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/oralLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@color/my_yellow"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="openNutrition"
                android:tag="oral" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/oralTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/oral_care_caps"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/oralArrow"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Methods for changing and animating the views:**

```
public void openNutrition(View view) {
        String viewTag = view.getTag().toString();
        if (viewTag.equals("wet")) {
            nutrition = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wetLayout);
            nutritionSub = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wetSub);
            nutritionTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wetTitle);
            nutritionArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wetArrow);
            animate();

        } 

        else if (viewTag.equals("dry")) {
            nutrition = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dryLayout);
            nutritionSub = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drySub);
            nutritionTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dryTitle);
            nutritionArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dryArrow);
            animate();
        }

        else if (viewTag.equals("mixed")) {
            nutrition = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mixedLayout);
            nutritionSub = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mixedSub);
            nutritionTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mixedTitle);
            nutritionArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mixedArrow);
            animate();

        }

        else if (viewTag.equals("oral")) {
            nutrition = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.oralLayout);
            nutritionSub = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.oralSub);
            nutritionTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oralTitle);
            nutritionArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.oralArrow);
            animate();

        }

        else if (viewTag.equals("changeMix")) {
            nutrition = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.changeMixLayout);
            nutritionSub = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.foodTypeLayout);
            nutritionTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeMixText);
            nutritionArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.changeMixArrow);
            animate();
        }
    }

    private void animate() {
        if (nutritionSub.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            nutritionSub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            nutrition.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            nutritionTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.my_yellow));
            nutritionArrow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.arrow_right_orange));
            r = new RotateAnimation(currentPos, degrees,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            /* Setting arrow animation properties */
            setArrowAnimation();

            Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
            nutritionArrow.startAnimation(r);
            nutritionSub.startAnimation(slideDown);
        } else {
            nutrition.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.my_yellow));
            nutritionTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            nutritionArrow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.arrow_right_white));
            r = new RotateAnimation(degrees, currentPos,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            /* Setting arrow animation properties */
            setArrowAnimation();

            Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
            slideUp.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    nutritionSub.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            nutritionArrow.startAnimation(r);
            nutritionSub.startAnimation(slideUp);
        }
    }

    private void setArrowAnimation() {
        r.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        r.setDuration(500);
        r.setFillEnabled(true);
        r.setFillAfter(true);
    }
```

`nutrition`,`nutritionSub`,`nutritionTitle`,`nutritionArrow` are declared as global private variables

**Update**

Running a log on my fragment class that extends `Fragment` and on `OnPageChangeListener`'s method `onPageSelected()` shows that tags are set properly and visible. The issue seems to be related to the lifecycle of fragments since the changes to the text and image only occur when I flip through ALL three fragments and then return to the second. 

Setting the pager:

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
pageAdapter = new NutritionPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
    fragments);
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

`getFragments()`

```
private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    fList.add(NutritionFragment.newInstance("Menu"));

    fList.add(NutritionFragment.newInstance("Nutrition"));

    fList.add(NutritionFragment.newInstance("Transition"));
    return fList;
    }
```

My `Fragment` class

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_TITLE = "FRAGMENT_TITLE";
    private View v;

    public static final NutritionFragment newInstance(String string) {
        NutritionFragment f = new NutritionFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
        b.putString(FRAGMENT_TITLE, string);
        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String screen = getArguments().getString(FRAGMENT_TITLE);
        if (screen.equals("Menu")) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_menu_activity_layout,
                    container, false);
        } else if (screen.equals("Transition")) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_transition_activity_layout,
                    container, false);
        } else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_nutrition_activity_layout,
                    container, false);
        }

        return v;

    }
```

Comment: Tried running a log or debug break point to check that your viewTag's are getting set as expected?

Comment: @zgc7009 I ran a log and the tags are setting as expected, when the layout second layout gets inflated. I tried to bypass the tags all together by using ids and the bug still persists.